# Copy and paste cells with random values

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

My VBA code is:

```
Sub hello()
Dim i As Long

Sheets("Sheet10").Select

For i = 3 To 101
Cells(i, 21).Value = Cells(2, 21).Value
Cells(i, 22).Value = Cells(2, 22).Value
Sheets("Sheet10").Calculate
Next i

End Sub
```

`Cells(2,21)` and `Cells(2,22)` contain a random formula, it could be `=RAND()` for simplicity. I would like to:

1. Copy `Cells(2,21)` and `Cells(2,22)`
2. Paste `Cells(2,21)` and `Cells(2,22)` value in the next `i` row;
3. Refresh `Cells(2,21)` and `Cells(2,22)`
4. Repeat until `i` is equal to `101`.

What I get instead is that when `i=52` the sub miss point 3. and from `i=52` to `i=101` I get the same values. How can I address this issue?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't use [`RND`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/rnd-function) in VBA?

Comment: Yes, the actual formula isn’t rand and it is more complicated (like a weighted mean of other random cells)

Comment: When I set some cells `=RAND()` and then set a few hundred other cells equal to the `.Value`, my values are all different and randomized. The `.Value` changes after each loop even without calling `Worksheet.Calculate`. I am unable to replicate your issue.

Comment: The two cells refer to a weighted mean of other random cells in other worksheets

Comment: Still, I set two cells to have a formula like `=RandCellA*2 + RandCellB*3` and then pushed their `.Value` to a hundred other cells in the column, the values are all randomized. I was not able to replicate your issue.

Comment: "other random cells in other worksheets" - but you only calculate Sheet10?  Maybe you need to re-calculate the whole workbook.

Comment: @TimWilliams this could work, I am going to try

Comment: Do the random formula include the range being filled ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you seem to be pulling values from other sheets, not just Sheet10, maybe you need to perform a larger recalculation:

```vb
Sub hello()

    Dim i As Long
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet10")
        For i = 3 To 101
            .Cells(i, 21).Value = .Cells(2, 21).Value
            .Cells(i, 22).Value = .Cells(2, 22).Value
        Next i
        Application.Calculate 'note this affects all open workbooks
    End With 'fixed

End Sub
```

Comment: This is not working for me, it says `Compile error: Next without For`

Comment: Sorry - I had `Next i` in place of `End with` - perils of editing code in the browser...

Answer (score 0):

### Columns of Random Values

- On each iteration, it will write the values of a one-column range (`srrg` (`srrgAddress`)) to a row of a 2D one-based array (`dData`) and recalculate the range containing a 'random-formula'.
- It will write the values from the array to the worksheet starting with the cell in a row (`dfRow`) of the first column of the range.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub hello()
    
    Const srrgAddress As String = "U2:V2"
    Const dfRow As Long = 3
    Const dlRow As Long = 101
    
    Dim srrg As Range: Set srrg = Sheet10.Range(srrgAddress)
    Dim cCount As Long: cCount = srrg.Columns.Count
    
    Dim drCount As Long: drCount = dlRow - dfRow + 1
    Dim dData() As Variant: ReDim dData(dfRow To dlRow, 1 To cCount)
    
    Dim dr As Long
    Dim c As Long
    
    For dr = dfRow To dlRow
        For c = 1 To cCount
            dData(dr, c) = srrg.Cells(c).Value
        Next c
        srrg.Calculate
    Next dr
    
    Dim dfCell As Range: Set dfCell = srrg.Cells(1).EntireColumn.Rows(dfRow)
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dfCell.Resize(drCount, cCount)
    drg.Value = dData
        
End Sub
```